# How can I get image from different project on the laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-5.3, assets

I have two project or url

First url like this :

http://myshop.dev/

Second url like this :

http://backend.myshop.dev/

If the second url, I run this :

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/$photo }}"/>
```

It will call url :

http://backend.myshop.dev/img/image1.jpg

It did not suit my needs

I want to take the image in the first url (http://myshop.dev/img/image1.jpg)

Both projects use the same database

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your .env

```
BACKEND_URL=http://backend.myshop.dev/public/
```

Call

```
<img src="{{ env('BACKEND_URL') . "{img/$photo}"}}"/>
```

Comment: I need you help again. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030452/how-can-i-upload-image-to-different-project-on-the-laravel

Answer (score 0):

You could store the image on an Image hosting service there are my google it.

If you are using different servers then you could use Rsync to automatically copy all uploaded images to the second server [Checkout how to use rsync](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps)

If you are using a single server to host both URI then you could just use a common folder and fetch the image from the common folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a helper for assets like that:

So instead of:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/$photo }}"/>
```

you should write

```
<img src="{{ myshop_asset('img/$photo }}"/>
```

in your helper.php:

```
if (!function_exists('myshop_asset')) {
    function myshop_asset($path)
    {
        $myshop_path = 'http://myshop.dev';//or read a config variable

        return rtrim($myshop_path) .'/'. ltrim($path, '/');
    }
}
```