# How can I upload image to different project on the laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-5.3, image-uploading

I have two project or url

First url like this :

http://myshop.dev/

Second url like this :

http://backend.myshop.dev/

If the second url, I upload image it will save the image file here :

http://myshop.dev/img/image1.jpg

Both projects use the same database

My code to upload image on the second project like this :

```
public function __construct(...)
{
    ...
    $this->path  = './img';
}
...
public function store(...) {
    ...
    $filename = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    ...
    Input::file('photo')->move($this->path, $filename);
    ...
}
```

It works

If I upload image it will save the image in backend-myshop\public\img

But, I want to uploaded image not saved there. But in my first project

So, I want the image file saved here : myshop\public\img

How can I do it?

Comment: So, you want uploaded image for first project to store at public\img\ folder and for second project some where else ?

Comment: @Sagar Gautam, Yes. So I want the uploaded image to be saved in the first project. While the upload process / code to upload image from the second project

Comment: As I understand, You want to write code in second project to save file inside public/img of first project. Am I right ?

Comment: @Sagar Gautam, Yes. It is true

Comment: Does  both project are in same server ?

Comment: @Sagar Gautam, Yes, Seems the projects are in same server

Comment: Then you have to provide full path of the folder in first project where you will store file and don't forgot to ensure correct permission levels

Comment: And also, public_path() won't work since you are uploading image file to another project

Answer (score 0):

Hi after uploading copy them from backend-myshop\public\img to myshop\public\img you can use this storage copy method

```
public function store(...) {
    ...
    $filename = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    ...
    Input::file('photo')->move($this->path, $filename);

    Storage::copy('backend-myshop/public/img/'.$filename, 'myshop/public/img/'.$filename);
    ...
}
```

hope this will solve your problem